# switch off logging statements in outputLOG for a particular java thread

Tags: java, multithreading, log4j, slf4j

I am running a heavy java application.
There is one thread which does polling and logs all debug statements.
I cant change logging level as this change affects other threads.

Is there any possible way to switch off debug statements for a particular thread in java?This would help to get 'outputLOG' file in customer site very specific.

Can you please help me on this?

Comment: you mean a thread instance or a given thread class ?

Comment: It s a 'thread' instance.This particular thread instance should not log it's debug statements even if mark LOG4j as 'debug' mode.But,I want all other threads to debug it's statements.

Comment: Why not pass a boolean to activate/deactivate the logs for an instance. I do not think you can activate deactivate logs on instances by log configuration...

Comment: I am spawning the thread through java executor.How to do that?Can you explain me ?

Answer (score 1):

I see two simple solutions:

- Pass an instance of a `Runnable` with either true or false for the logging
- Or they may be an internal way to detect you are in a specific situation depending on other data you pass to the Runnable

Comment: Can you show me an example of 'Pass an instance of a Runnable with either true or false for the logging'?

Comment: `new MyRunnable(true);` where MyRunnable is your Runnable class